# Output MySQL results with a line for each row in terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal, pipe

I've tried to use the following command in order to select all databases in the same line:

```
mysql -s -u root -p -e "show databases;"
```

However it displays the row representing all available databases in multiple lines.

Example:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

But I would like the output to be like this:

```
foo bar baz
```

The `show databases` query is an example, it would also help me any solution that can display each selected row in the same line.

The `--silent` option doesn't seem to be working properly:

```
s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
                   each row on new line.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a query instead of a command.  The following query will place all the databses in a list separated by spaces:

```
SELECT group_concat(SCHEMA_NAME separtor ' ') as databases
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

You would execute this as:

```
mysql -s -u root -p -e "SELECT group_concat(SCHEMA_NAME separtor ', ') as databases FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA"
```